# Find where the tangent line passes through the origin.

Tags: calculus, trigonometry

I need help finding where the tangent line of $f(x) = 5 \cos(3x)$ passes through the origin.
I know the equation of a tangent line is $y = f'(a)(x - a) + f(a)$.
So I my first thought was to set y and x equal to zero, then solve for a. Is this correct? If so can you help me solve for a, because I got stuck.

Answer (score 1):

First calculate the points where the tangent line goes through $(0,0)$; you just have to solve $f(x)/x=f'(x)$.  In our case, any number $x$ satisfying $-3x\tan(3x)=1$ is the first coordinate of such a point.

Answer (score 0):

Your approach is correct. $f'(x)=-15\sin(3x)$, so the T.L. passing thorugh the point $(a, f(a)$ is  $y=-15\sin(3a)(x-a)+5\cos(3a)$. It passes through the origin if $a$ satisfies the equation $0=15a\sin(3a)+5\cos(3a)$. But I dont know how you can solve this eqn. Perhaps you may use WalframAlpha.

Comment: you did a mistake on equation it's $y=15asin(3a)+5cos(3a)$

Answer (score 0):

You'r right, you just have to developp your tangent equation:
$f'(a) = -15 \sin(a)$
So equation becomes:
$$0 = 15 a \sin(3a)+ 5 \cos(3a)$$
So you have to study function $g(x) = x \sin(x)+\cos(x)$ and find x so that $g(x) = 0$

Study of g:
$$g'(x)=x \cos(x)$$
First $g(\pi/2)=\pi/2$ and $g(\pi)=-1$

Also $\forall x \in $ $\left]\pi/2, \pi\right]$, $g'(x)<0$

So since g is decreasing in $\left]\pi/2, \pi\right]$ then $\exists x_0 \in \left]\pi/2, \pi\right[ $, $g(x_0)=0$